# How to set datacontext for each combobox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm having a problem about binding in combobox ( WPF, MVVM).
I have a combobox, which binds to AViewModel ( for example).
To do that, I did have:
- AModel
- AViewModel
- Xaml file :

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:AViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

It works fine.

But, now, I add one more combobox to the same form with combobox above. This combobox binds to diffirent ViewModel (BViewMoel for example, note that, this BViewModel located in diffirent file with AViewModel above).
And this is combobox xaml:

```
<ComboBox 
    DataContext="BViewModel" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="BName"/>
```

My problem is: the second combobox is not populated because it does not have datacontext.
But I cannot set datacontext for it because it is set above for AViewModel.

I did a lots of searching but I still stuck in this.
Should I merge all ViewModels into a ViewModel and set this to Datacontext of Window or any ideal?
Thank you.

Comment: You have a viewmodel for every combobox? I'd suggest to rethink your approach...

Comment: @you could create an separate ViewModel as container

Comment: The normal MVVM approach is a 1 on 1 view to viewmodel relation. Unless in some very rare occasions, you shouldn't have multiple viewmodels for 1 view.

Comment: No, I have 1 view and 1 viewmodel. as I said, ACombobox binds to AViewModel and BCombobox binds to BViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combobox1.DataContext = new AViewModel();
combobox2.DataContext = new BViewModel();
```

But I suggest using a ViewModel contains two properties.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public AViewModel AViewModel{get;set;}
    public BViewModel BViewModel{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works like charm. :).
For your suggest. Do you mean I should create a new ViewModel contains others ViewModel and then set it as DataContext of Windows like this:
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:AllViewModela/>
</Window.DataContext>
?

Answer (score 4):

Really, I wouldn't use a ViewModel for each combobox. Combobox is a simple control, you should bind the `ItemsSource` property to a public property (of type `ObservableCollection<T>` for instance) of the ViewModel of the owner view.

Sometimes it's useful to use a ViewModel for a specific and complex usercontrol. In this case, you can expose the viewModel as a public property of the ViewModel of the owner view:

```
public class UCViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}

public class MyViewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewViewModel()
    {
        this.UCViewModel = new UCViewModel();
    }

    public UCViewModel UCViewModel { get; set; }
}

<Window x:Class="MyView">

    <MyComplexUsercontrol DataContext="{Binding UCViewModel}" />

</Window>

public partial class MyView : Window
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewViewModel();
    }
}
```

But again, for a simple combobox, just bind it to a property of the ViewModel associated with the owner view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, actually, I have set ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}" ( MyList here is a ObseravleCollection<T> property).

Comment: I still think use viewmodel for each combobox ( or datagrid, listview..) is a flexible way.

Comment: @Dat No, trust me, it's not. Adding ViewModels adds complexity for no benefits in your case.

Comment: @Dat: He is right. One view, one ViewModel bound as `DataContext`. Everything else, will be a mess, sooner or later. But it's your call.

Comment: @ken2k: you mean: in my case, I should merge AViewModel and BViewModel into a unique ViewModel ( AllViewModel for example)?. Then set AllViewModel is DataContext of Window. Sorry I'm very new in WPF and MVVM, so my question could be a little stupid. :(

Comment: @DHN: Yes, I'm doing one view, one ViewModel, just little bit complex.

Comment: @Dat Basically, you should have one viewModel for each View. The view is bound to the viewModel (via the `DataContext`). The ViewModel exposes multiple public properties. Each control (combobox, label, textbox...) of the view should be bound to a property of the viewModel. In the case of a combobox, you can bind `ItemsSource` to an observable collection. But there isn't any other viewModel in this simple scenario.

Comment: @ken2k: Thank you so much, I think I understand you. You mean: I should create a viewmodel called MyComboboxViewModel ( for instance). Then, in MyComboboxViewModel, I will have 2 observable collections for each combombox to bind to, and other public properties for others view ( textbox, label...).?. So, i just need 1 ViewModel for entire my window. ?.

Comment: @Dat Yes, that's it: 1 ViewModel for your entire window, and public properties in this viewModel for all controls of your window. But may be you shouldn't name your ViewModel "MyComboboxViewModel", but something more related to the business of your view (for example: UserCreationViewModel).